# Onde é armazenado um arquivo de sessão do PHP?

Tags: php, session

Já li sobre arquivos relacionados a `$_SESSION`, mas eu gostaria de encontrar eles. Onde eles ficam armazenados?

Comment: No servidor, o que fica no cliente é o cookie.

Comment: Não tem necessidade de encontrar ele, isso cheira a criar uma grande falha de segurança ou gambiarra, o ideal é obter pelo $_SESSION.

Comment: Não acho justo os downvotes, apesar da simplicidade da pergunta, esse controle de localização é importante, principalmente para que usa algo como PHPRC (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/configuration.php) e pretende isolar "coisas", ou até trabalhar múltiplos domínios, não vou entrar em detalhes, de antemão deixo o meu +1, apesar de acreditar que a pergunta como foi escrita levou a um entendimento um pouco diferente, tanto que pelo meu comentário anterior nota-se que a pergunta me fez crer que necessitava de fato pegar os arquivos. Dê qualquer forma agora entendo a motivação real da pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A localização do armazenamento da variável `$ _SESSION` é determinada pela configuração [`session.save_path`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) do PHP. Normalmente, o caminho é `/tmp` em um sistema Linux/Unix.

Use a função [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.phpinfo.php) para ver suas configurações se não tiver 100% certeza da localização. Basta criar um arquivo `.php` com esse código na `DocumentRoot` do seu domínio:

```php
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

---

### Observação

Como dito nos comentários, e também muito importante ressaltar:

> De forma simplificada, pode utilizar a função [`session_save_path()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-save-path.php) que controla essa diretiva.

Se você utilizar [`session_save_path()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-save-path.php) conseguirá, simplificadamente descobrir a localização do armazenamento das variáveis de sessão:

```
<?php
    echo session_save_path();
?>
```

---

Também temos uma pergunta respondida sobre isso no nosso [Grande Irmão SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/454635).

Comment: Foi ninja, quase consegui responder ao mesmo tempo, mas hoje o selo Rubens Barriquelo é meu xD kkkk . +1

Comment: De forma simplificada, pode utilizar a função [`session_save_path`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-save-path.php) que controla essa diretiva.

Comment: Realmente @AndersonCarlosWoss, vou adicionar essa outra maneira também.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss no caso ele disse aonde esta o padrão, o que me parece correto dentro do que foi perguntando, de qualquer forma se vcs lerem a pergunta vão perceber que parece que o AP parece querer fazer uma gambiarra o que pode causar uma baita falha de segurança.

Answer (score 1):

No servidor, claro, não faria sentido manter este controle no cliente, esta informação é necessária justamente para a aplicação manter algum estado entre as requisições.